# Django API for login/logout with S3 site is not creating cookies

Tags: django, jquery, web-applications

I'm working with a static webpage hosted on S3 and I'm using a Django as my api for session management.

I have my JS code on S3 POSTing to django when users sign in to my web site but I'm not getting any cookies saved on my browser.

I'm not sure if it's the jQuery $.post that is not accepting cookies or if it's Django that's not allowing the sending of cookies. How would I overcome this?

I currently also have a url endpoint on my django app where I can check if cookies are working but when I hit the url I get the standard message

```
Please enable cookies and try again.
```

Although my browser accepts cookies.

I get these urls to work fine when I use a Django rendered page to interact with them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks

**Edit - showing code:**

I use Janrain to allow user to login via facebook, twitter, etc..

how Janrain works

1. user clicks sign in button, uses facebook/wtv to login
2. Janrain get's user data on their servers and gives you a token which I post to django via this function

janrain.events.onProviderLoginToken.addHandler(function(tokenResponse) {

```
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: post_form_url,
            data: formdata + "&token=" + tokenResponse.token,
            success: function(res, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //do stuff now that we are logged in ...
                console.log(jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie')); //returns null
                //$('#redirect').submit();
            },
        });
```

**In Django**

```
def login_via_janrain(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        janrain_token = request.POST.get('token')

        // communicate w/janrain api to get info from this token (i.e. who just logged in via this token)

        #create (or pull) user based on data returned from janrain api and do a Django login

        auth.login(request, user)

        #return success msg to $.post (session cookies should be automatically included in the response)

        return HttpResponse("success")
```

**Using S3**

I currently have a static site hosted on S3. I tested these urls using django rendered views but ultimately I want the S3 site to render the views and just use django as an api endpoint.

I can currently login from the S3 site but after a successful login I have no cookies to show for it... I think django isn't sending back cookies...

Comment: show your code, please, so we can see what you are doing

Comment: I just added my code to the question, I took out the messy stuff